# Convergence of light by light scattering amplitude

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, scattering

Perhaps I'm too exhausted to see the answer of why the photon-photon scattering should contain no divergences. In Peskin and Schroeder page 320 we find that because of the Ward identity the photon-photon scattering amplitude expanded in a Taylor series in the external momenta must start at $\sim p^4.$ Then they go on and claim that the superficial degree of divergence is therefore $$D_{\gamma\gamma\rightarrow\gamma\gamma}=0-4.$$

So my question is why is the photon photon scattering amplitude not divergent? Where did the $0$ and the $4$ come from.

There's another derivation of this given by Mathew Schwartz as seen in the [screen capture](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic473482.files/21-renormalizability.pdf#page=2) from his lectures. Although this does not directly answer my question regarding the $D=0-4.$
[image]

EDIT: haha Tumbleweed collected for this. Is the question so boring, really?